# Setting inputAccessoryView for a UitextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just want to make the UITextField to go up when keyboard was presented. I achieved it by setting the frame of UITextField after keyboard was presented. It is working for ordinary cases. But, if user enabled prediction in default keyboard then predictive text area gets placed above the UITextField. In that case I want the text field to move up. I tried setting inputAccessoryView of textfield. But app crashed with no report .So how can I set inputAccessoryView of textfield to achieve my requirement.

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bottomToolbarView.frame.size.width, bottomToolbarView.frame.size.height)];
textField.delegate = self;
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
textField.inputAccessoryView = bottomToolbarView;
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
[textField setPlaceholder:@"Enter Employee Id"];
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.720 blue:0.611 alpha:1.000]];
[bottomToolbarView addSubview:textField];
```

[image: Simulator Image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code in textfield Did Begin Editing delegate method

```
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;

CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size. height;

CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;

CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

& on didEndEditing delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField1
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

   [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
   [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Bro I don't want to use this method of changing the frame of UITextField each time when keyboard is shown or hidden because keyboard height is not constant and it is different in Iphone 6 & Iphone 6 plus. So guide me to achieve this with inputAccessoryView of UITextField because this method is much more efficient and universal then previous one.

Comment: It will work for all types of device screens such as iphone 6,6+

Comment: inputAccessoryView is for setting Toolbar or for displaying Pickerview on textfield

Comment: Keyboard height is different in 4s, IPhone 6 and 6+. Tested it in simulator and result is  4s = NSRect: {{0, 480}, {320, 253}}, 6 = (CGRect) keyboardFrameBeginRect = origin=(x=0, y=667) size=(width=375, height=258), 6+= (CGRect) keyboardFrameBeginRect = origin=(x=0, y=736) size=(width=414, height=271). See height of keyboard is different. Think of different Ipad and their orientations. So in your way we have to add lot of if checks and needs regular updation for every new launch of Iphone.  So I'm preferring to get solution through inputAccessoryView, which is automatically handled by apple.